# FIWARE Wirecloud: which template files are actually used?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

We are customizing a Wirecloud installation to provide our own branding, text and header links. We have created a subtheme to the 'defaulttheme' and are overlaying our own template, images and sccs files to accomplish our customization.

We have managed to change the header image, landing page and a few other bits, but are hampered by the following:

1. The generated HTML provides no clues as to which template it originated from (we think?)
2. Documentation here: https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/platform/themes/
   specifies a number of template files, but not all of the template. For example we cannot find the place where the 'Sign in' button is defined.
3. The wirecloud javascripts seem to insert random bits of html for what should be boilerplate stuff. For example a 'Powered by wirecloud' icon appears at the bottom of the screen. The 'get more components' button appears out of nowhere and we cannot disable it.
4. Many of the generated elements do not have an id, so it is difficult to disable or identify them in a sccs file. The 'get more components' button for example is not relevant for us, but we cannot remove it (so far).

Does anyone have a completed custom theme we can look at? Or can someone point out which template files / sccs files are used for branding and overall look-and-feel?

Answer (score 0):

1. True, currently WireCloud doesn't print any comment not any other clue for detecting from what template the html was generated.
2. Some parts are not generated using templates, for example, the "Sign in" button. I recommend you to create a ticket in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) for each thing you want to customise and you don't find how to do it, so we will be able to give you a better answer, and to create a template if needed.
3. Remember that you have to include a "Powered by WireCloud" to comply with the WireCloud license. In the other hand, the "get more components" button can be removed by editing the [`wirecloud/workspace/wallet/wallet.html`](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/blob/develop/src/wirecloud/defaulttheme/templates/wirecloud/workspace/wallet/wallet.html) template, by removing the following code:

   ```
   <s:southcontainer>
       <t:addmore/>
   </s:southcontainer>
   ```
4. Well, this can also be discussed and documented. We usually don't use ids because those elements are better located using some kind of selector.

Anyway, we are working to improve the documentation about themes ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Alvaro. Regarding point (2); trial and error is not a good approach i think. Are there no other Wirecloud users that have documented what they ran into while customizing? Regarding point (3), our issue is with the link behind the button that points the user to "https://conwet.fi.upm.es/wirecloud/". Surely the license does not oblige us to add a link to upm.es? The http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html license page does not state this.